# C# How to create array from .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays

New to C# 
Trying to figure out how to create an array from an exisitng .txt file.
Call text file "filename"
File contains pairs of elements separated by coma such as:

AGT, H

ATT, M

TAA, J

AAG, I

Eventually I need to pair these up again in a dictionary, but I don't think I need to use a 2D array, unless it's easier.
Any suggestions???
All ideas and advice is welcomed as I am new to C# and needing to learn VERY quickly.

Thank you!!

Comment: Looks like a job for pre-written dedicated csv parser to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a `string[]` from the columns. Then you could get a  `IEnumerable<string[]>` in this way:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(l => l.Split(','));
```

If you want to materialize the query to a collection you could use `ToList` or `ToArray`:

```
List<string[]> lineList = lines.ToList();
```

If you want to create a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead (duplicate keys are not allowed):

```
var dict = lines.Select(l => l.Split(','))
               .ToDictionary(split => split.First(), split => split.Last());
```

Comment: By using the 1.Split(',') method, it keeps them paired? And if so, can I still assign them as Keys and Value in a dictionary?

Comment: @novicebytes: yes, you get a `string[]` for every line. You can access them via indexer or linq methods like `First()` or `Last()`. If you need a dictionary(note that duplicate keys are not allowed): `var dict=lines.ToDictionary(l=>l.Split(',')[0],l=>l.Split(',')[1]);`

Comment: This is part of a much bigger program where lines of code such as AGTAATTAAGTA are written and the program needs to use the .txt file to convert them into the Keys along the right column of that file.

Comment: So after I have the .txt file converted into an array, I need to assign the array to a dictionary for keys and values, have the program search the lines of code for the "Key" and output the "Value"

Comment: So a line of Code such as AGTATTAAG will output HMI

Comment: Does all of this make sense?? Does it sound to you like I'm on the right track?? File to array, array to dictionary, for loop to scan the data, output values?

Comment: @novicebytes: Maybe you want to ask another question for this Problem. It is not really clear from the comments and i must admit that i need to go to bed now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the lines, split each line into an array with two items, then fill a dictionary from it:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict =
  File.ReadLines(filename)
  .Select(l => l.Split(new string[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None))
  .ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
```

Comment: for some reason my IDE is not liking the .ToDictionary call. I have the System.Linq parameter called by it still doesn't want to recognize it.  Any ideas?

Comment: @novicebytes: It was the `Split` method that was the problem. To split on a string the parameters are more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ReadAllLines(String)`.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a dictionary using some LINQ :)

```
File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);
```